# How to concat storageuri & SAS token and how to upload a blob using concated storageuri & SAS token using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, azure-storage

I am working with Azure. I want to upload a blob using SAS token in c#. Please explain how to concatenate StrorageUri & SAS token and how to upload in windows c#

This my sample storage Uri:

```
 https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer/
```

This is my sample SAS token:

```
sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D
```

Comment: Are you using .Net SDK for Azure Storage or will you be uploading using REST API?

Comment: I'm using .NET SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wish to upload a file named `myfile.txt` using SAS, you could do something like below:

```
//Create storage credentials using SAS Token.
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D");

//Create blob URI...https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/blob-name.
var blobUri = new Uri("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer/myfile.txt");

//Create an instance of CloudBlockBlob using this URI and storage credentials.
var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri, storageCredentials);

//Call methods on that CloudBlockBlob object.
cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(...);
```

Comment: Thanks bro.I have one doubt. how to I mention file(myfile.txt) source location. For eg: file present in below location D:/test/myfile.txt

Comment: Please check the documentation for UploadFromFile method of CloudBlockBlob.